# django give access to a page after entering a password to see content

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to make a page protected by password in `django` I mean that to see the **content** of the page you need to enter a **password** and you don't need to be logged to do that

Comment: Yes, It's possible.

Comment: Can I see some example? I have search the internet and all I found its about user authentication

Comment: anyway, I added an example.

Comment: Protecting page (a particular URL) is possible, you need to choose the right option. 
One way to do it - via your Web Server (e.g. Apache HTTPD supports .htaccess). 
Other options can be: decorators. You may also develop your view to verify for "password" key in your GET/POST method. 

You can choose existing password verification code and add into your views to verify your key (that can be 'password' key). 
You can also go via OTP route. 

Try to share your code - some one can always correct or guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the `password` is passing through *URL query parameter*

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def sample_view(request):
    try:
        if request.GET['password'] == 'thepassword':
            return HttpResponse("Correct password")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Wrong password")
    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponse("You should provide 'password'")
```

Comment: And can I somehow do that for a full `django app`?

Comment: NVM found this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.__setitem__